# Solve $\sin 2x = \sin(x-\frac{\pi}6)$

Tags: trigonometry

I got a this equation to solve and $\sin(2x) = \sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$

They was nice to give me for possible answers it could be.

x = $\frac{\pi}{6}$

x = $\frac{\pi}{18}$

**x = $\frac{7\pi}{18}$**

x = $\frac{55\pi}{18}$

After i calculated i thought it was **x = $\frac{7\pi}{18}$** because I first solved $\sin(2x) = \sin(x-\frac{\pi}{6})$ and got it to around 1.22 and **x = $\frac{7\pi}{18}$** was the only option that got the same value. But it turned out to be wrong.

Comment: Please use `\sin` instead of `sin` in function names, compare the difference $\sin$ vs $sin$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice $\sin A=\sin B$ iff $A=B+2k\pi$ or $A=\pi-B+2k\pi$, $k\in\Bbb Z$.

So, $\sin 2x=\sin (x-\frac{\pi}6)$ iff

$$2x=x-\frac{\pi}6+2k\pi$$
or
$$2x=\pi-x+\frac{\pi}6+2k\pi$$

That is,

$$x=-\frac{\pi}6+2k\pi$$
or
$$x=\frac{7\pi}{18}+\frac{2k\pi}3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check that we have

$$\sin\alpha=\sin\beta\iff\begin{cases}\alpha=\beta\;,\;\;or\\{}\\\alpha=\pi-\beta\end{cases}\;\;\;+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the $\arcsin$, both members are equal or complementary, to an even multiple of $\pi$.
$$2x=x-\frac\pi6+2k\pi\lor\pi-2x=x-\frac\pi6+2k\pi$$
$$x=-\frac\pi6+2k\pi\lor x=\frac{7\pi}{18}+\frac23k\pi$$
Possible answers are

$$-\frac\pi6,\frac{11\pi}6,\frac{23\pi}6,\frac{35\pi}6..., \color{blue}{\frac{7\pi}{18}},\frac{19\pi}{18},\frac{31\pi}{18},\frac{43\pi}{18},\color{blue}{\frac{55\pi}{18}},\frac{67\pi}{18}...$$